# poltergeist onConsoleMessage initialization on Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist, ui-testing

I'm using the phantomjs driver via poltergeist on ruby/capybara. One thing I'm trying to setup is the ability of receiving debug messages from javascript into the ruby debug console.

I see that phantomjs has a javascript `OnConsoleMessage` callback to set up this, but I couldn't find a way to wire this up from ruby. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that you need to enable the inspector

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {debug: true, :timeout => 90, :inspector => true})
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

and then place

```
page.driver.debug
```

somewhere on the spec, which will bring a link to the inspector dashboard. It doesn't reload by default, so you need to hit reload from time to time to see changes